# StackOverflowException on nested query, small item count

Tags: c#, .net, linq, stack-overflow

I have found some threads with similar titles, but none seem to have a fitting answer.
One mentioned a bug in .NET versions prior to 4.0 - I use 4.0, so this should not be it.

Consider the example:
I am attempting to create a collection of instances of class Part, which do not belong to any instance of class PartGroup.

```
Func<Part,bool> hasGroup = P => partColl.Groups.Any( G => G.Parts.Contains(P) );
var groupless = partColl.Parts.Where( P => ! hasGroup(P) );
```

partColl is an instance of a class implementing the properties Groups and Parts, each `IEnumerable<T>` where T is PartGroup or Part respectively, internally implemented as `List<T>`.
partColl.Parts contains all parts in existence.
class Group has property `IEnumerable<Part> Parts`, listing references to parts belonging to the group.

In my current program, there are 27 parts and 5 groups with no overlap in elements.
Nothing that should trouble the stack, despite quadratic complexity, if something wasn't foul.
When I run this, it will crash with said exception on hasGroup.

What am I missing?

---

**EDIT:**
A little detail slipped my abstraction presented here:
IEnumerable PartGroup.Parts was, unlike the two properties of PartCollection, not backed by a List, it was an auto-property with private set, initialized in the c'tor with a passed-in IEenumerable. The instance behind this IEnumerable is also a list, and an own one for each group, so I'm not sure yet what is going on exactly.

**BUT, the exception is gone by**: also backing that property with a variable of type List and in the constructor, assigning to it: _list = parts.ToList(), where parts is `IEnumerable<Parts>`, passed as a param to the ctor. I did ToList just to make sure it will really be a list, not some half baked query, but it should, since at the place where I am building the groups, one new List for each group is allocated before passing it in...

The remaining question is still interesting: What was going on, why did the auto-property 'cause' the exception?
I'll post more details on request, but gotta go for a while now.

Comment: What is the stack trace leading up to the exception? It might crash because hasGroup uses stack but something's gone wrong earlier in the piece.

Comment: All the stacktrace shows is calls to three distinct anonymous methods, intertwined with [External Code] in a pattern like:
__5(..) [External] __4(..) __6(..) [External] ...repeated, and at the end it says: "The maximum number of stack frames supported by Visual Studio has been exceeded."

Looks endless-loopy to me, I don't get why, though

Comment: Are you overwriting Equals or GetHashCode?

Comment: no, but see updated main post

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

This small sample does not reproduce the issue.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class P
{
    class PartGroup
    {
        public List<Part> Parts { get; private set; }
        public PartGroup()
        {
            Parts = new List<Part>();
        }
    }

    class Part
    {
    }

    class PartCollection
    {
        public List<Part> Parts { get; set; }
        public List<PartGroup> Groups { get; set; }
        public PartCollection()
        {
            Parts = new List<Part>();
            Groups = new List<PartGroup>();
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var groups = new List<PartGroup> { new PartGroup(), new PartGroup(), new PartGroup(), new PartGroup(), new PartGroup() };
        var partColl = new PartCollection();
        partColl.Parts.Add(new Part());
        partColl.Groups.AddRange(groups);
        for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
        {
            var part = new Part();
            groups[i % groups.Count].Parts.Add(part);
            partColl.Parts.Add(part);
        }
        partColl.Parts.Add(new Part());

        Func<Part, bool> hasGroup = P => partColl.Groups.Any(G => G.Parts.Contains(P));
        var groupless = partColl.Parts.Where(P => !hasGroup(P)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually was writing an example like that to see whether I was missing a detail, then found one... see updated first post